# Why is my container not storing properly with Aspect Oriented Programming?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

This is probably due to a misunderstanding, but I have the following class:

```
@Aspect
public class Example {
   @Getter
   private Box b1 = new Box();

   @Around("execution(p2())")
   public Object p1(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
      this.b1.enter("from p1()");
      System.out.println("from p1()");
      return jp.proceed();
   }

   public Object p2() {
      this.b1.enter("from p2()");
      System.out.println("from p2()");
      return null;
   }
}
```

and my `Box` is just a vector wrapper

```
public class Box {
   private Vector box = new Vector();

   public void enter(String s) {
      this.box.add(s);
   }

   public void show() {
      System.out.println(this.box);
   }
}
```

Now I tried executing

```
Example e1 = new Example()
e1.p2();
```

and surely enough, I see on my console:

```
from p1()
from p2()
```

the `@Aspect` part is working, but my `Box` isn't registering all the entries! If I try

```
e1.getB1().show();
```

I only see `from p2()` in the box. Clearly `p1()` is being called but it is not being entered in the box. What is going on here?

Comment: The aspect is a separate instance. Box registered the entrance, but it was a different Box.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Is Aspect secretly creating another `Example` instance?

Comment: Nothing secret about it. The method is part of Example, true, but Aspects run outside of your manually created lifecycle. So if you call `el.p1()`, then it'll add it to the box in the Example instance you made. But the aspect also needs an instance to operate on, so it uses reflection or the default constructor to instantiate its own.

Comment: Is there a way to get around this? Ideally I'd like to keep my `Logger`

Comment: Your pseudo code does not even compile. Also you do not explain where your `@Getter` annotation comes from - maybe Lombok? Beware, Lombok and AspectJ have some incompatibilities, so you would have to delombok before applying aspects. Another question is why the aspect would want intercept one of its own methods? This code example is so contrived, it gives me the creeps from a design point of view. Anyway, I will try to answer your question because it is obvious what is going on. But please, do refactor this mess. No offence meant, I do want to help you.

Comment: You ask a lot of AspectJ questions lately. I would appreciate if you would also provide feedback when you get an answer. Please verify, then accept and upvote my answer or tell me if you still have problems. Afterwards I can delete this comment again.

Answer (score 0):

By default, AspectJ aspects are singletons. Other instantiation models are available, but yours definitely is a singleton, automatically created by the AspectJ runtime. Now your own aspect constructor call `new Example()` creates another instance. As Roddy already stated correctly, this is why you are not dealing with a single instance anymore, thus also not with a single `Box` member.

If you want to get access to an AspectJ-managed singleton aspect instance, you ought to use `Aspects.aspectOf(MyAspect.class)`, see also the [AspectJ manual](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-aspectof.html). Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - sorry I could not resist renaming a few fields and methods to at least make this very strange code a little bit more readable:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.Vector;

public class Box {
  private Vector box = new Vector();

  public void enter(String s) {
     box.add(s);
  }

  public void show() {
     System.out.println(box);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Box;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  private Box box = new Box();

  public Box getBox() {
    return box;
  }

  @Around("execution(* doSomething())")
  public Object myAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
    this.box.enter("myAdvice");
    return joinPoint.proceed();
  }

  public Object doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Doing something");
    this.box.enter("doSomething");
    return null;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.aspectj.lang.Aspects;

import de.scrum_master.aspect.MyAspect;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyAspect myAspect = Aspects.aspectOf(MyAspect.class);
    myAspect.doSomething();
    myAspect.getBox().show();
  }
}
```

When running the application, the console log will be:

```
execution(Object de.scrum_master.aspect.MyAspect.doSomething())
Doing something
[myAdvice, doSomething]
```